# Python: Permission denied problem on Android

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, save

I just wanted to save `.mp3` file from a website in `/storage/emulated/0/Download` folder on Android, but I always get `Errno 13 Permission denied`.

here's example code:

```
import requests

# full path to mp3 file in website example
target_link = 'https://www.yt-download.org/download/IFtwhMK64H8/mp3/128/1630338605/f2803874069bf196561631cea2b1b11c2b1d2f9555e2baf751eb28b46d484bb5/0.mp3'

r = requests.get(target_link)

# downloading it into download folder on Android
with open('/storage/emulated/0/Download/file.mp3', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Update:
Forgot to say that I used Kivy as GUI framework.

Comment: How are you making it run, on Android? What are you using? 
Writing privileges on Download folder require a particular permission, on Android. Please, provide informations about the environment

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to say that I did simple GUI using Kivy and KivyMD, and I just deployed this application on android.

Comment: I have `INTERNET, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permisissions.

Comment: Having `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` listed doesn't automatically grant you that permission. You also have to prompt the user through the OS and ask them to accept it. Listing that permission only informs the Android OS you intend to ask for this specific permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You surely need the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.
On latest Android versions, that permission must be requested explicitly.
You then have to use something like this:

```
from android.permissions import Permission, request_permissions, check_permission

def check_permissions(perms):
    for perm in perms:
        if check_permission(perm) != True:
            return False
    return True

perms = [Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE]
    
if  check_permissions(perms)!= True:
    request_permissions(perms)
```

This will ensure that you have all the required permissions and that the user explicitly granted them. Note that you must check them everytime, because the user can revoke them outside the app.

The rest of your code looks ok, even if I'd better use primary_external_storage_path(), instead of providing an absolute path.

Comment: Hmm, I thought having `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in buildozer.spec file will let my application download whatever it want. Well, thank you for your answer.

Comment: That's the correct behaviour for Android versions previous of 7.0 (I might be mistaken for the version). From that version on, the write_external_storage requires explicit permission. It is mentioned in Android documentation, but I'm not sure Kivy's documentation mentions it.